# Как сделать update вместе insert в Spring Data?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

***У меня имеется такая вот сущность:***

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Message {

    @Id
    private long id;

    private String recipient;
    private String subject;
    private String text;

    private boolean sent;
    private String status;

    @Column(name = "expire")
    @CreationTimestamp
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
    private Date expire;

    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    @CreationTimestamp
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
    private Date updatedAt;

    @Column(name = "created_at")
    @CreationTimestamp
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
    private Date createdAt;

    @PreUpdate
    protected void onUpdate() {
        updatedAt = new Date();
    }
}
```

***И такой тестовый контроллер:***

```
@RestController
public class MessageTestController {

    @Autowired
    private MessageService messageService;


    @RequestMapping("/testMessage")
    public Message testMessage(@RequestBody Message message) {
        System.out.println(message.getId());
        System.out.println(message.getRecipient());
        System.out.println(message.getStatus());
        System.out.println(message.getSubject());
        messageService.save(message);

        return messageService.findById(0);
    }

}
```

***Проблема в том, при отправке контроллеру `json` в таком формате***

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "recipient": "samoilov.s@natalie-tours.ru",
    "subject": "some subject",
    "text": null,
    "sent": false,
    "status": "NOT NOW 2",
    "expire": "2017-06-27 09:42:41",
    "updatedAt": "2017-06-27 09:48:27",
    "createdAt": "2017-06-27 09:42:41"
}
```

***возникает такая ошибка***

```
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "message_pkey"
```

Но если я сделаю `messageService.findById(0)` и потом `save` полученного элемента, то `update` произойдет успешно. Почему так ?

Если над `id` поставить аннотацию `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)`, то будет происходить `insert` новых записей с новым `id`, но не `update`. При этом в `json` я передаю `id` напрямую.

Comment: Могу предположить, что когда Вы делаете сначала  messageService.save(message);, то объект message неперсистный, а new (или Transient) и HIBERNATE полагает, что Вы создали новый объект и в БД его нет. Поэтому Hibernate делает insert. Он не делает предварительную проверку есть ли объект с ID=0 в БД. А когда Вы сначала сделаете find, то HIBERNATE создаст в кэше персистный объект с ID=0 и при save будет понимать, что объект с  id=0 уже есть и надо делать update.

Comment: продолжение. Попробуйти использовать утилиту, для просмотра содержимого кэша перед и после вызовом этих двух методов в разных порядках.  http://konopkomikl.ru/2017/06/20/hibernate-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d1%8d%d1%88%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b8-first-level-persistence-context-cache/

Comment: Upadate и Insert - это разные операции. На них нужно сделать два различных метода. Один для POST запроса - это insert, второй для PUT/PATCH запроса - это update.

Comment: @Cepr0 кому нужно ? Я понимаю, что по `rest` архитектуре так положено, но ведь речь совсем не об этом...

Comment: @Orthodox помог Ваш комментарий. Могли бы отметить его как ответ и я бы отметил его как правильный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

когда Вы делаете сначала messageService.save(message);, то объект message неперсистный, а new (или Transient) и HIBERNATE полагает, что Вы создали новый объект и в БД его нет. Поэтому Hibernate делает insert. Он не делает предварительную проверку есть ли объект с ID=0 в БД. А когда Вы сначала сделаете find, то HIBERNATE создаст в кэше персистный объект с ID=0 и при save будет понимать, что объект с id=0 уже есть и надо делать update.

Попробуйти использовать утилиту, для просмотра содержимого кэша перед и после вызовов этих двух методов в разных порядках.

[Содержимое кэша](http://konopkomikl.ru/2017/06/20/hibernate-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8-first-level-persistence-context-cache/)